# Position this footer correctly in IE? (links to examples inside)

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Could someone with access to Internet Explorer possibly figure out what's wrong with this page?

Someone with IE told me the footer(s) are not displaying properly - they are not staying at the bottom.

There are two footers - a small one that starts with "Coming up", which is stacked on top of a larger one with links, copyright, etc. in it.

This page is with content that should be longer than the browser window:

https://eggzample.github.io/halp.html

This one has content that does not fill the browser window.

https://eggzample.github.io/halp-short.html

It looks fine in Firefox on Linux:

https://eggzample.github.io/screenshot-short.png

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Please see about how to write a good question in SO: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - links to external sites will go old over time and anyone reading this in the future will not understand what was being answered. Please produce a short, verifiable version of the problem.

Comment: I felt it a bit much to expect others to download pasted html and css in order to provide help.  I am unable even to isolate the code which is at issue since I don't have access to IE.  

The html and css at the URL I pasted will remain as long as github is gracious enough to host the content.  I created that account specifically to host examples.